# Output filename and count of a directory in a text file - windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch to output filename and count of filenames with the same prefix and date in a text file.

E.g.

> Q1231111.zip
>
> Q1241111.zip

where:

- Q123 - is a prefix
- 1111 - is a date.

I want an output such as:

> 123 : 1
>
> 124 : 1
>
> 125 : 0

But the batch file unable to output the last one. I wanna see the file is present so i need the 0 output.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q1231111.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"
for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q1241111.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"
for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q1251111.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"

for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=#=" %%I in ('set Group# 2^>nul') do echo %%I: %%J >>count.txt
endlocal
goto :EOF

:CountFile
set "FileName=%~1"
set "FileGroup=%FileName:~1,4%"
if "Group#%FileGroup%" == "" (
    set "Group#%FileGroup%=1"
) else (
    set /A Group#%FileGroup%+=1
)
goto :EOF
pause
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's printing `1251: 1` but you said you wanted only "125". Did you mean `set "FileGroup=%FileName:~1,3%"` instead of `set "FileGroup=%FileName:~1,4%"`?

Comment: Also did you mean "count filenames with the same *prefix*" (instead of same date)?

Comment: i mean the batch only output those with 1. all the prefix in the batch should be outputted whether its 1 or 0. the count should be counted based on prefix and date.

Comment: So under what circumstances are you expecting it to output 0? Your current batch file outputs 1 for 123, 124 and 125. What is so special about 125 that you want it to output 0?

Comment: was just about to ask the same. I get exactly `1231: 1` 
`1241: 1` 
`1251: 1` which is what I would expect.

Comment: Ooooh wait. Are you actually trying to find the files in the directory and do the count of these files, but Q125111.zip is not there and you expected it to be 0?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it's hard to tell exactly what you are looking for. But by looking at your very similar question from a year ago, and from Gerhard's comment, I think what you're looking for is:

Count the number of files with a given prefix, each file having a different date suffix.

I think this should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "Group#123=0" & for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q123????.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"
set "Group#124=0" & for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q124????.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"
set "Group#125=0" & for %%I in ("Z:\StoreDataJDA\Q125????.zip") do call :CountFile "%%~nI"

(for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=#=" %%I in ('set Group# 2^>nul') do echo %%I: %%J)>count.txt
endlocal
goto :EOF

:CountFile
set "FileName=%~1"
set "FileGroup=%FileName:~1,3%"
set /A Group#%FileGroup%+=1
goto :EOF
```